# Postgres transaction to use UPDATE instead of INSERT if a row already exists

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, postgresql-9.1

A simple problem from a Postgres newbie:

How do I write a Postgres transaction something like

```
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE myPK = myValue > 0 THEN
UPDATE myTable ...
ELSE
INSERT INTO myTable...
END
```

I want this in the hopes that it can solve a bug in my web app that occurs when another insert happens on myTable between my being able to `SELECT COUNT(*)` from it to decide whether I should update or insert.

Comment: Many similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+upsert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a sample plpgsql implementation for this in Postgresql's documentation: see [merge_db](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE)

It is specifically meant to support concurrent update-or-insert (often referred to as UPSERT).